# Recommended strategies for using Github PATs on RPi

Tags: git, security, github, raspberry-pi

*RPi.stackexchange found this question OT for their site and recommended here.  I'm not convinced but will give it a go.*

The switch to personal access tokens on Github is causing me some serious headaches when it comes to programming and development on the RPi. The issue is how to efficiently and securely provide the PAT to a new RPi. On a fresh install, I first run git config --global credential.helper store and then pull from an undisclosed source (say, for example, a NAS on my local network) a copy of .git-credentials that contains (in plaintext) my token.

This method is reasonably efficient (I'm only required to access the NAS) but is clearly not secure. It's also not appropriate for a public setting (for example, I'm fine doing this with my hobby projects at home on my local network, but less so in my research lab were students are working on their own RPis and need to perform similar tasks).

Are there recommended strategies for efficient push/pull github access that also make a reasonable attempt (defined here as better than plaintext) at securing the PAT?

Comment: Is the problem regarding how to transfer the PAT in a secure way?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame yes, along with how they are properly (securely) stored in a RPi/Linux environment.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to secure these on the Pi itself? If you're going to use them non-interactively, either (a) you need to store the credentials in plaintext, or (b) you need to store the credentials encrypted and then store the encryption key in plaintext...which mostly defeats the purpose. What's the threat model from which you're trying to protect yourself?

Comment: @larsks My biggest concern is primarily pedagogical.  As mentioned in the question, I use this process for my hobby-projects at home, and so am unconcerned with the security risk.  In a teaching setting, I would like to guide students on best practices, or at least provide a *caveat emptor* so they understand the risks of the practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can use to grant access to a repository.  You've mentioned personal access tokens, but if you only need access to one repository, you're probably better off using a deploy key with SSH.  That would grant either read-only or read-write access to a single repository, and avoids some of the risks to the rest of your repositories from that single machine being compromised.

You could do this by having the Raspberry Pi generate a key, grabbing the public part over the network, and adding it as a deploy key using the API (to which you will authenticate with a personal access token on your local machine).  This would be secure; only the Raspberry Pi would have the secret portion, and you wouldn't need to share any secrets over the network.

If you're logging into the Raspberry Pi over SSH, then you could also just use your own SSH key and forward the agent with `ssh -A`, and then you can push and pull without needing to actually copy any credentials.  This is also secure.

If your problem is how to secure access to a private repository when the device is open to public access, then there is no secure way to do that, as I'm sure you had guessed.

It's unclear to me what you were doing before, but if it was just that you were typing your password when prompted, then you could still do that by copying and pasting a PAT from a password manager, but it's probably just easier to use an SSH key in that case.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph - I was using a password.  The RPi's I work with are not headless. I often restart projects from a fresh image, but if a PW manager exists that functions from the CLI and is a one line (apt-get) install, then that would be viable as well.  I will try SSH as I am usually focused on one repository per RPi project.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two-folded: how not to store your key in plain text and how to transfer it safely to the other device(s).

There are several ways to encrypt a text file, e.g. with [openssl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162960/how-can-i-encrypt-a-file).

To transfer your key from one device to another, assuming you have access to an internet connection on your RPi, you can use a secure transfer program like [Magic Wormhole](https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Both solutions require a passage involving communicating the passwords, that can be made via another communication channel and should be made safely (e.g., verbally communicating the OpenSSL password).